# Oracle ORDER BY input value

Tags: oracle, sql-order-by

I want to order query according to input value. If input value is str1 then I want to order by 1 ASC and if it is str2, I want to order it by 2 DESC.

I wrote something like that:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN 'input' = 'str1' THEN 1 ASC WHEN 'input' = 'str2' THEN 2 DESC END
```

How do I need to modify it to get desired result?
I can do `ORDER BY 'input'` but it's sorting only in ascending order.

Comment: I didn't clearly understand it. Could you explain it please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Link provided by @user7294900 contains the solution for your question.
Basically, all you have to do is implement the CASE section correctly.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE SOMETHING = 'something'
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN INPUT = 'str1' THEN 1 END,
CASE WHEN INPUT = 'str2' THEN 2 END DESC;
```